# Android query vs rawQuery results

Tags: android, database, sqlite

When I run either of the queries below with a normal 13 digit barcode a result is returned from my database perfectly fine. However when I run the exact same code with an 8 digit barcode the result is not found in the second query even though it exists in the DB. To me the queries look identical. What could be going wrong?

```
return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE bcode = '"+bcode+"'", null);

return mDb.query(DATABASE_PRODUCT_TABLE,new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_BCODE,KEY_USEBY_DAYS}, KEY_BCODE + " = " + bcode, null, null,null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the 8-digit barcode have leading zeroes, by any chance? Because WHERE clause in the second example is wrong.

Comment: Indeed the barcode does. I assume it the missing single quote marks that are to blame?